# jQuery .index() always returning 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to make a block of code happen depending on the index of the the element that is clicked. The problem is that no matter which element I click it spits out 1.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.container .product a').click(function() {
    var a = $(this).index();
    
    alert(a);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-body">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <a href="#">Buy Me!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-body">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <a href="#">Buy Me Also!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-body">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <a href="#">M Three!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

It is because calling `$(this).index()` will return the index of `this` based on its siblings and in your case `a` is always the second child of its parent

Since you want the index of `a` based on the set `.container .product a`, you can use either of the below variants of [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $as = $('.container .product a').click(function() {
    var a = $as.index(this); //or $(this).index('.container .product a');

    alert(a);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-body">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <a href="#">Buy Me!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-body">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <a href="#">Buy Me Also!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-body">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <a href="#">M Three!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the extra step and explaining why, your description helped me understand it a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

For more details about `index()` method, look at [Jquery - index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.container .product a').click(function() {
     var a =  $(".container .product a").index( this );        
     alert(a);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-body">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <a href="#">Buy Me!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-body">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <a href="#">Buy Me Also!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-body">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" />
      <a href="#">M Three!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```